# Gradle apk file missing dependencies

Tags: android, eclipse, gradle, apk, myeclipse

I am new to Gradle.  I have been looking for a solution to my problem for several hours now but cannot get my build to work correctly. Basically I have an Android project that I am trying to build using Gradle. I have a libs directory in my project that contains dependencies.  It appears the build knows that they are there because it uses them when compiling the application.  However, when the apk is assembled the dependencies are not in the apk.  I am trying to get this to generate an apk file that is similar to the apk that is generated when you perform an Export from MyEclipse.  The apk generated from the MyEclipse export has a lib directory as well as an org directory so I know the dependencies are in that apk.  The apk generated from Gradle has neither.  Here is my build.gradle file.

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.1.0'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 17
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    dependencies {
        compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
    }

    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src']
            resources.srcDirs = ['src']
            aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
            renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
            assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
        }

        instrumentTest.setRoot('tests')

        debug.setRoot('build-types/debug')
        release.setRoot('build-types/release')
    }
}
```

Comment: Overall I am trying to automate my deployment via Jenkins. I was able to use a Jenkins Plugin called Android Emulator Plugin.  With this I was able to generate Ant build scripts(Configure->Add Build Step-> Create Android build files).  After that I then added an Ant build step to run the build.xml file that was created.  With no extra configuration it was able to build my apk the way it needed to with the dependencies.  There was a noticeable size difference as well.  However, I would still like to know what was the problem with Gradle.  I may need to use it in the future.

Comment: Okay after looking through the apk more it appears the .jar dependencies were compiled into the apk.  I had another folder within libs that had 2 .so files that needed to go into the apk.  I need to research how to do this via the build but until then I added these to the apk manually in the lib directory just like Ant produced(not sure the effect this has if negative).  The apk still failed to load onto my device.  I will probably continue using Ant for the build.

Comment: All your dependencies are there: compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')